# Ruby-Rails Exporting search results table to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using the CSV class to do result exporting to csv. I have it working now, but it only exports my search query to CSV, not the results (which are displayed on my 'show; page).

> search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

 def to_xls(options = {})
  {
      "Id" => id.to_s,
      "firstname" => firstname,
      "surname" => surname,
      "officenumber" => officenumber,
      "department" => department,
      "division" => division,
      "address" => address,
      "notes" => notes
  }
 end
end
```

> searches_controller.rb

```
def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xls { send_data @searches.to_xls, content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'search.xls' }
    end
end
```

> mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls
```

Comment: Where does `@searches` come from? It's not shown where that originates.

Comment: I don't see the code anywhere in your question that shows the CSV export, so it's not possible to see if the right data is being processed.

Answer (score 2):

You Should try this one,

```
def self.to_xls(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |product|
      csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

Link should be like `<%= link_to "Excel", your_path(format: "xls") %>`

You can find complete flow [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) to implement it.